# How to grab a user's Fivestar voting value with Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, comments, rating

On my website, users can rate nodes via comments. The Fivestar field is called 'Stars'. I'd like to use the user's voting value in a rule that's activated when a new comment has been saved. (The rule should update a radioactivity field, called 'Popularity', from the node that's commented on.)

When debugging the 'Stars' field in a comment, I'm able to get exactly the value I need via `field_stars['und'][0]['rating']`. However, I can't find a way to grab it in the Rules UI. I'm always ending up with `comment:field-stars:` in an action.

I tried adding a condition 'Entity has field: *Parameter: Entity: [comment:node], Field: field_stars*'. This gave me the option to dig deeper to `comment:field-stars:user-rating`, but when I'm using it further on in my rule, it always throws an error "The variable or parameter value is empty."

What's going wrong and how can I solve this?

---

**Edit**: After reading [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52884/setting-a-variable-in-php-for-use-in-rules), I tried solving my problem with the following rule.

```
{ "rules_new_vote" : {
    "LABEL" : "New vote",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php", "radioactivity", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert--comment_node_article" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "comment:node" ], "field" : "field_popularity" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : "0" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "null" : "null" } }
        }
      },
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$rating = \u0026drupal_static(\u0027rating\u0027, $default_value = $comment-\u003Efield_stars[\u0027und\u0027][0][\u0027rating\u0027]);" } },
      { "radioactivity_emit" : {
          "data" : [ "comment:node:field-popularity" ],
          "value" : { "select" : "null", "php" : { "code" : "return $rating;" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly: when saving a comment, the following error is thrown:

> Notice: Undefined variable: rating in eval() (line 1 of
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(146)
>   : eval()'d code).

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error could be caused from `return $rating;`, not the other code. Are you sure that those two code blocks have access to the same PHP variables?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Indeed, the error is caused by the `return`, but I don't know how I can solve it. I thought using `drupal_static` would make the variable `$rating` available later on in the rule, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Use `return drupal_static(...);` instead of `return $rating;`. It is not a problem with `drupal_static()` but with using a variable that is not set. In other words, the second block of code doesn't know about `$rating` because it doesn't share PHP variables with the first block of code, where you call `drupal_static()`.

Comment: See line #146 in [php.eval.inc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!modules!php.eval.inc/7) and [rules_execute_php_eval()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!modules!php.eval.inc/function/rules_execute_php_eval/7) (the function calling the one causing the error you are seeing). It doesn't seem that the variables used in your first block of code are going to be shared with your second block of code (the `return` part).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I've figured it out (at last!) without using `drupal_static`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem. This is my exported rule:

```
{ "rules_new_vote" : {
    "LABEL" : New vote",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php", "radioactivity", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert--comment_node_article" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "comment:node" ], "field" : "field_popularity" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : {
              "select" : "comment:cid",
              "php" : { "code" : "$comment = comment_load($value);\r\n$vote = $comment-\u003Efield_stars[\u0027und\u0027][0][\u0027rating\u0027\r\nif ($vote == 20) {return -4;}\ r\nif ($vote == 40) {return 2;}\r\nif ($vote == 60) {return 3;}\r\nif ($vote == 80) {return 4;}\r\nif ($vote == 100) {return 5;}" }
            }
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "rating" : "Rating" } }
        }
      },
      { "radioactivity_emit" : { "data" : [ "comment:node:field-popularity" ], "value" : [ "rating" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

The trick was to store the `cid` as a new variable and to use that value in the PHP evaluation (the proposed values in my code can be changed to your needs). I've no idea why this wasn't possible in an easier way via the UI, but maybe it's a bug in the Firestar module.